# Jquery's function by action starts on page load

Tags: jquery

I can do this:

```
$("#icon").live("hover",
    function() 
    {
        var position = $(this).offset();
        $('#popup').css({top: position.top - 10, left: position.left + 20}).toggle();
    },
    function()
    {
        $('#popup').toggle();
    }
);
```

But this:

```
function show_popup(element)
{
    var position = element.offset();
    $('#popup').css({top: position.top - 10, left: position.left + 20}).toggle();
}
$("#icon").live("hover",
    show_popup($(this)),
    function()
    {
        $('#popup').toggle();
    }
);
```

errors `position is null` on the page load.

Why does it run show_popup() on the page load? And what is wrong with that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
show_popup($(this))
```

is a function call so it will be executed when `live` is being set up for execution, you want just a function in there. When `show_popup($(this))` gets executed, `this` will probably be `window` and `window` doesn't have an offset, that means that your `position` inside `show_popup` will be `null` and there's your error message. Also note that this approach tries to bind the return value of `show_popup` (which will be `undefined`) as a jQuery callback and that's clearly not your intent.

You want something like this:

```
$("#icon").live("hover",
    function() { show_popup($(this)) },
    function()
    {
        $('#popup').toggle();
    }
);
```

Or perhaps this:

```
function show_popup()
{
    var position = $(this).offset();
    $('#popup').css({top: position.top - 10, left: position.left + 20}).toggle();
}
$("#icon").live("hover",
    show_popup,
    function()
    {
        $('#popup').toggle();
    }
);
```

In this case you always have to supply the appropriate context when calling `show_popup` so you'll be doing a lot of things like `show_popup.call(some_dom_element)` if you want to call `show_popup` anywhere that isn't a jQuery callback.

Answer (score 0):

The use of "element." is invalid in this case. making position unuseable.
if you did something like

```
var position = $('#'+element).offset();
```

thats likely help fix the issue. Note I prepended an "id" (#) selecter and not a "class" (.) selector to the call as well of course you can edit it accordingly